# How to fuzzy match column names from more than two data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe as below-

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'lname':['a','b','c'],
    'fname':['A','B','C'],
    'mname':['q','i','u'],
    'ssn':[1,2,3]
})
```

[image]

and second dataframe is:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name':['aa','bb','cc'],
    'last_name':['AA','BB','CB'],
    'middle_name':['qq','ii','uu'],
    'social_security_number':[11,22,32]
})
```

[image]

Here on concatenating these two dataframe it shows an output as:

```
pd.concat([df_1,df_2])
```

[image]

As we know that (first_name, fname) , (last_name, lname) and (ssn, social_security_number)are same in general.

Considering this if if do concatenate these two frames it should show an output:

[image]

Comment: Are they always in the same order? you can use `pd.concat([df_1, df_2.set_axis(list(df_1), axis=1)])`

Comment: No. They are not.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to rename the columns' names?

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'lname': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'fname': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'mname': ['q', 'i', 'u'],
    'ssn': [1, 2, 3]
})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
    'last_name': ['AA', 'BB', 'CB'],
    'middle_name': ['qq', 'ii', 'uu'],
    'social_security_number': [11, 22, 32]
})
df_1 = df_1.rename(columns={'lname': 'last_name',
                     'fname': 'first_name',
                     'mname': 'middle_name',
                     'ssn': 'social_security_number', })
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
print(df)
```

Comment: What if I have more data frames ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. If you have more data frames, then change them all (with loop if necessary).